# Laravel - read database credentials from a remote api

Tags: laravel, database-connection

There is a central web app 'AppsManager' that stores users and database credentials for all other web apps. This has an api to validate the login in other web apps and also serves database credentials.

So in a different laravel app -that has it's own database- I am asked to implement a different way of using database credentials.

The request is forLaravel to read it's database credentials from the 'AppsManager' api instead of the default .env file.

Is this a good practice ? How can be done in Laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good practice or not, personnally I dont think it is a good idea to have credentials sent between apps.

Nonetheless, what I would do, in your situation, is create a new configuration in `config/database.php` to explicitly tell Laravel what connection it should use to have this distant database.

Inside the models that use this database you can specify :

```php
<?php

class MyModel extends Model {
    protected $connection = 'name-of-the-connection-you-gave-in-the-config-file';

}
```

Or if you use the `DB` facade, you can just call `DB::connection('name-of-the-connection-you-gave-in-the-config-file')` as explained [here in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections).

Comment: Thanks, I knew this already as this is also in the laravel docs